# iOS simulator : take same page screenshot Edited

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, screenshot

I have an app I want run it on many iOS simulator and take screenshot for the app to use them on publishing the app .
the problem on each simulator it take the first screenshot page I take for the all other pages

### view this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MCCbuRJH18&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Restart you simulator from `Device -> Restart`. Then take screenshot.It will work.

[image: See attached screenshot]

Comment: is that mean for each screenshot I want to take must restart the device?

Comment: No..Only one time

Comment: Then reset your simulator Device -> Erase All Content and Settings...

Comment: I must restart device each time